# Wordpress menu displays posts with specific year

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want create menu in Wordpress theme where menu items are: '2016', '2017', '2018'. Every year must link to all post from specific year. In which file should i loop this posts? Do i have to create 3 separate pages for each year and in each file i must add code like that:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
  'year'  => 'SPECIFIC YEAR',
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

      the_content();

  endwhile;
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
$args = array(
    'type'            => 'yearly',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'post_type'     => 'post'
);
wp_get_archives( $args );
```

Comment: but in which file ?